# Swap Class of Element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="more">text</a>
```

How can I toggle the class between "more" and "less" when clicked?

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('more', 'less');
});
```

But I get the class changing from "more" to "" and not to less.

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">text</a>

$("a#toggle").toggleClass("more");
$("a#toggle").toggleClass("less");

or you can chain them together.

$("a#toggle").toggleClass("more");
             .toggleClass("less");
```

The key is: toggleClass will just add/remove that class in the parameter. It will not toggle between the classes in the parenthesis.

Comment: I really wonder why this has been marked as answer. 1) using tagname with id is inefficient and slow, just id is enough 2) calling toggleClass twice can be reduced to just once as in my answer which is more efficient and does the same job

Comment: I think Shapper just need to figure out why `toggleClass()` doesn't work as he originally expected. @PSL, your solution is also an elegant alternative indeed.

Comment: its not about elegance when you can do with just one call why need two calls , well his syntax is incorrect in the question, if you see he passes them as argument.

Comment: PSL, I understand your feeling. But all Shapper need is to understand how `toggleClass()` works. Both our answers can satisfy that need. Probably he feel my description is more detailed and help him more. I don't know. And please don't get angry with this kind of petty stuff. It just won't be worthy of your time.

Comment: it it not about petty or angry lol, my answer could be wrong as well right. So a feed back as a courtesy is always good, if it did not work out well, i will learn a new thing as well. Also regd description that is present in my answer as well. So was just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Using toggle and specifying [multiple class names](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className) you can achieve this. It will just remove the class name(s) that is present and add that is (are) absent. But you should make sure that atleast one of them is present on the element first up.

```
$this.toggleClass('more less');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkP57/)**

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't answer to your suggestion. The problem is I wasn't sure if I will always have a "more" or "less" class on my anchor. I needed to check this ... And in fact I think I might also have situations where the class is empty ... I am still figuring out the best way solve this.

Comment: @Shapper if that is the case same issue will happen with the other answer as well. It just does the same but in a less efficient way. And also all these were not part of your question as well.